# Data Labels Being Swallowed in Area Chart in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Stacked Area Chart in SSRS 2008 R2.

[image]

As you can see, the data  labels are swallowed both left and right.
If I change the chart type to any area chart I have the same problem.
If I change to line type, it leaves space between the y axis and the chart.

Do you know any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a real solution to my issue. Playing with the Label, SmartLabels and NoMoveDirections properties didn't affect my chart at all - strange.

So I removed the axis and gave made the fill for the data labels as the corresponding areas. It looks like this:

[image]

Better than nothing...

Answer (score 1):

By default, smart labels are placed in static positions. You can allow them to be moved by changing the NoMoveDirections properties. In your case, it looks like changing Left and Right to False should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: I have all as False. Just to test I changed to True and I get the same result.